# Hovering link to question show the wrong title based on link itself

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

I see a link to this post: [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Here it is:

[image]

As you can see, the question is named "how can i convert" with lower cases but the question have well upper cases.

And for example, if we use it as duplicate : [image] it's fine.

As rene explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379269/1059914), it's because we can set what we can in the link and it will be showed with `-` replaced.

Is that possible to change it to real title instead of possible wrong informations?

Comment: Not a bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379269

Comment: Thanks for answer @rene . But as you explained in your answer, it can showed wrong informations. Does it should be a feature request (to add the real title)?

Comment: As it is not a bug, this needs to be a FR then. I'm not sure how many users will fancy that feature. And then I can still do [Wrong title here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379269/Got-you-there)  and those won't be updated either.

Answer (score 3):

I just made the userscript [SmartPostLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SmartPostLinks.user.js) to solve this. On top of question title, it will also display: post type, author, author rep, date created, last activity date. It will also work in chat, and chat transcripts. It also generally works for post links from other sites on the Stack Exchange network (except the Hot Network Questions, which I disabled it otherwise it will make too many requests - one per unique site).

Userscript **SmartPostLinks** ( [source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SmartPostLinks.user.js) | *[install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/SmartPostLinks.user.js)* )

#### Screenshots

**Before (1):**
Misleading post slug resulting in incorrect title attribute

[image]

**After (1):**
Link text and title attribute corrected by Smart Post Links, and displays more post info

[image]

**Before (2):**
Unknown short link (also known as share/referral link), requiring you to click on it to view post title/details (no title attribute set - *no effect if you hover over such links*)

[image]

**After (2):**
Post title for short link is now displayed upfront in link text, and more post info in title attribute

[image]